# How to turn off all material "Use Nodes"

Tags: scripting

Does anyone know how to script or do this I need it badly I don't want to single handedly toggle off all the use node option for all of the materials.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured it out ;)

```
import bpy

for eachMat in bpy.data.materials:
    
    eachMat.use_nodes = False
```